# Using JDeveloper to develop a portlet for JavaFX project

Tags: web-services, javafx

Suppose I developed a JavaFX project using netbeans 6.8 (JavaFX SDK plugin installed), and right now I need to convert this JavaFX UI to portlet and display it in a web page.

And I'm only allowed to do this using JDeveloper. So how could I achieve this? I'm using Oracle WebLogic Service as my web application server.

-Regards from Isaac.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm able to resolve this is create portlet which embeds JavaFX applet inside.